# JSON only works if copy code literally, generated code does not work, why?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, format

I have following code;

```
var fechas = "";
for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
    var fechas = fechas + "{\"text\":" + "\"" + response.data[i].ADP_Asunto + "\"" + ", \"startDate\": new Date (" + response.data[i].ADP_FechaInicio.substring(0, 4) + "," + (response.data[i].ADP_FechaInicio.substring(5, 7) - 1) + "," + response.data[i].ADP_FechaInicio.substring(8, 10) + "), \"endDate\": new Date(" + response.data[i].ADP_FechaFin.substring(0, 4) + "," + (response.data[i].ADP_FechaFin.substring(5, 7) - 1) + "," + response.data[i].ADP_FechaFin.substring(8, 10) +",23,59)},";
}
fechas = fechas.substring(0, fechas.length - 1) + "";
var completo = "[" + fechas + "]";
console.log(completo);

 $("#scheduler").dxScheduler({
                                    dataSource: JSON.parse(completo);,
........................................................
```

And does not work, but if I copy console.log output and assign to "data", and then link to datasource, it works perfect;

```
 var fechas = "";
                            for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                                var fechas = fechas + "{\"text\":" + "\"" + response.data[i].ADP_Asunto + "\"" + ", \"startDate\": new Date (" + response.data[i].ADP_FechaInicio.substring(0, 4) + "," + (response.data[i].ADP_FechaInicio.substring(5, 7) - 1) + "," + response.data[i].ADP_FechaInicio.substring(8, 10) + "), \"endDate\": new Date(" + response.data[i].ADP_FechaFin.substring(0, 4) + "," + (response.data[i].ADP_FechaFin.substring(5, 7) - 1) + "," + response.data[i].ADP_FechaFin.substring(8, 10) +",23,59)},";
                            }
                            fechas = fechas.substring(0, fechas.length - 1) + "";
                            var completo = "[" + fechas + "]";
                            console.log(completo);
                           
                            var data = [{ "text": "ASUNTO NUEVO2", "startDate": new Date(2020, 0, 01), "endDate": new Date(2020, 0, 01, 23, 59) }, { "text": "ASUNTO NUEVO2", "startDate": new Date(2020, 0, 25), "endDate": new Date(2020, 0, 28, 23, 59) }, { "text": "Asunto nuevo Bo", "startDate": new Date(2020, 11, 31), "endDate": new Date(2020, 11, 31, 23, 59) }];  //   console.log(data);
                    
                            $("#scheduler").dxScheduler({
                                dataSource: data,
```

I tried jsons.parse/stringify, "[" + ... + "]" ... and nothing works

Comment: Did you tried without parsing/stringifying the object at all?

Comment: Yep, I tried with  dataSource: completo, and dataSource:fechas ,

Comment: I can't see any reason why `JSON.stringify(yourObj)` doesn't work.

Comment: JSON.stringify(fechas) returns in console.log;
    "{\"text\":\"ASUNTO NUEVO2\", \"startDate\": new Date (2020,0,01), \"endDate\": new Date(2020,0,01,23,59)},{\"text\":\"ASUNTO NUEVO2\", \"startDate\": new Date (2020,0,25), \"endDate\": new Date(2020,0,28,23,59)},{\"text\":\"Asunto nuevo Bo\", \"startDate\": new Date (2020,11,31), \"endDate\": new Date(2020,11,31,23,59)}"

Comment: JSON.stringify(completo) returns in console.log; "[{\"text\":\"ASUNTO NUEVO2\", \"startDate\": new Date (2020,0,01), \"endDate\": new Date(2020,0,01,23,59)},{\"text\":\"ASUNTO NUEVO2\", \"startDate\": new Date (2020,0,25), \"endDate\": new Date(2020,0,28,23,59)},{\"text\":\"Asunto nuevo Bo\", \"startDate\": new Date (2020,11,31), \"endDate\": new Date(2020,11,31,23,59)}]"

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031465/json-objects-inside-json-objects
 `For example, this is valid JavaScript, but not valid JSON:

var Person = {
    name: "John",
    birthDate: new Date(1980, 0, 1),
    speak: function(){ return "hello"; },
    siblings: [
        Andrew,
        Christine
    ];
}`

Comment: Can I edit something to get a valid JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it!  with the next code;

```
   var fechas = "";
for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
    var fechas = fechas + "{'text':" + "'" + response.data[i].ADP_Asunto + "'" + ", 'startDate': '" + response.data[i].ADP_FechaInicio.substring(0, 4) + "-" + response.data[i].ADP_FechaInicio.substring(5, 7) + "-" + response.data[i].ADP_FechaInicio.substring(8, 10) + "', 'endDate':'" + response.data[i].ADP_FechaFin.substring(0, 4) + "-" + (response.data[i].ADP_FechaFin.substring(5, 7)) + "-" + response.data[i].ADP_FechaFin.substring(8, 10) + "'},";
}
fechas = fechas.substring(0, fechas.length - 1) + "";
var completo = "[" + fechas + "]";
var myObject = eval('(' + completo + ')');
console.log(myObject);

$("#scheduler").dxScheduler({
    dataSource: myObject,
```